# In perl, How can I write an iterator that doesn't have big files behind the scenes?

Tags: perl, iterator

This iterator is adapted from dir_walk in Higher Order Perl.

```
sub dir_walk 
{   my @queue = shift; # push first directory onto FIFO queue
    return sub # this is the iterator
    {   if (@queue) 
        {   my $entry = shift @queue; # take the first item off the queue
            # Here if $entry is a Directory
            if (-d $entry && opendir my $dh, $entry) 
                {   # read all the files in the directory into an array
                    my @newfiles = grep {$_ ne "." && $_ ne ".."} readdir $dh;
                    # prepend the path to the file names
                    push @queue, map "$entry/$_", @newfiles; 
                }
              return $entry;
            } 
            else {return;} # ignore files here, they're in the queue
        };
}
```

It seems to be cheating in that it violates one of the main purposes of iterators, avoiding loading large arrays, by hiding the big arrays @newfiles and @queue inside the routine.
(OK, the files are only as big as the largest subdirectory, but still...)

Is there a way I could rewrite it so it could act more like the

```
while (<FH>){ }
```

for reading a file, avoiding unnecessary big arrays?

All I can think of is to save a DOS dir command to a file, and then read the file in, a line at a time as above. That would take a lot more parsing, and for all I know is also hiding big files somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

One fairly obvious way (but one requiring quite a bit more code) is to instead of reading an entire directory at a time and sticking all the names in the queue, wrap the `readdir` in another iterator and put the iterator in the queue. Then when using the queue, check if the front element is an iterator and if so pick items from it until it's exhausted instead of simply shifting the element off.

Comment: There's no need to "wrap" `readdir` in an iterator...`readdir` acts as an iterator in scalar context, so you could simply push an open directory handle onto the queue. But this doesn't change the OP's problem at all, since you're just swapping filenames for dir handles.

Comment: ThisSuitIsBlackNot's comment suggests an interesting alternative: Provide a callback routine as an argument to dir_walk, call readdir in scalar context, and handle the files there in the loop, dispensing with the big arrays.